# How can you programmatically empty a suppression list?

Tags: marketing-cloud, suppressionlist

Lists are somewhat more constrained than Data Extensions, but unfortunately, Suppression Lists (as opposed to excluding via DE) are the only way to suppress/exclude subscribers from Journeys.

This means we need to programmatically/automatedly 'overwrite' (or delete and rewrite) a suppression list. Has anyone successfully manage to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should review the concept of Auto Suppression Lists. https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/auto_suppression_lists/

Auto-Suppression Lists can be assigned to specific Send Classifications and therefore give you more flexibility. You can import directly into a Auto-Suppression List via an Import Definition which allows you to add or overwrite the Auto-Suppression List.

In case you shouldn't see Auto-Suppression List under e-Mail >>> Admin you can simply reach out to support asking for it to be enabled.

Comment: Thanks - I had ignored these as I had incorrectly assumed they behaved like other lists (and therefore don't allow overwrites), but digging into the documentation, it looks like they behave like Data Extensions, and therefore _can_ be overwritten!